# How to close all the apps when "my app" starts

Tags: java, android

I am a novice android developer and this may sound a bit silly, but I want to close all the running apps when my app starts, is it possible in Android ? If yes, Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Ask yourself, would it be good to allow an app to close other apps. For example to allow a malicious app to close your phone app and start it's own phone process so it can monitor you?

Comment: If you can explain why you want to do this, we can perhaps point you in a better direction.

Comment: thanks for the replies... infact this is my first question here.. i want to use Sensor in a way that no other app can use it in that time being.

Comment: which sensor, and what is so special about your way of using it that other apps would interfere?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly what you wish to do with this sensor. It is unlikely you will have to close other apps, the OS is designed to handle these situations e.g. with the camera

Answer (score 4):

Luckily you cannot do that on non-rooted devices now.